# Nginx not able gzip the response

Tags: nginx, webserver, gzip

Nginx is not able to gzip output response. 
I have confirmed it using chrome dev tools as well as using simple curl commands. Client (browser) is sending "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" while making HTTP request.

here is the nginx.conf file

```
 worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 5; 
    gzip_types  text/html application/x-javascript text/css application/javascript text/javascript text/plain text/xml application/json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-opentype application/x-font-truetype application/x-font-ttf application/xml font/eot font/opentype font/otf image/svg+xml image/vnd.microsoft.icon;
    gzip_static  on;

    server {
        listen  8080;

        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /home/ubuntu/project1/src;
            index  app.html;
        }
    }


    server {
        listen  8081;

        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /home/ubuntu/project2/src;
            index  app.html;
        }
    }
}
```

and mime.types file

```
types {
  text/html                             html htm shtml;
  text/css                              css;
  text/xml                              xml rss;
  image/gif                             gif;
  image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
  application/x-javascript              js;
  text/plain                            txt;
  text/x-component                      htc;
  text/mathml                           mml;
  image/png                             png;
  image/x-icon                          ico;
  image/x-jng                           jng;
  image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
  application/java-archive              jar war ear;
  application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
  application/pdf                       pdf;
  application/x-cocoa                   cco;
  application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
  application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
  application/x-makeself                run;
  application/x-perl                    pl pm;
  application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
  application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
  application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
  application/x-sea                     sea;
  application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
  application/x-stuffit                 sit;
  application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
  application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
  application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
  application/zip                       zip;
  application/octet-stream              deb;
  application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
  application/octet-stream              dmg;
  application/octet-stream              eot;
  application/octet-stream              iso img;
  application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;
  audio/mpeg                            mp3;
  audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
  video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
  video/quicktime                       mov;
  video/x-flv                           flv;
  video/x-msvideo                       avi;
  video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
  video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
  video/x-mng                           mng;
}
```

curl command

```
curl http://myserver/templates.js --silent --write-out "%{size_download}\n" --output /dev/null

curl http://myserver/templates.js --silent -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" -H “Accept: text/javascript” --write-out "%{size_download}\n" --output /dev/null
```

Both command returns same number of bytes (17414 in this case).
i may be not able to share content of `template.js`

Comment: Show curl and file

Comment: @AlexeyTen i have included `curl` commands in question description

Comment: Your `mime.types` doesn't contain `text/javascript` or `.js`. Show `curl -v ....` response

Comment: i have tried with `application/x-javascript`. No effect

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding few other attributes. It worked for me when i added the following in `nginx.conf` file :

`gzip_min_length 1000;`

Really Strange behaviour ! According to docs its default value is `20`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html